# Build tautologies and satisfiable formulas in haskell

Tags: haskell

I encounter some difficulties trying to understand how to build tautologies and satisfiable formulas. I am working on problem that requires me to emulate a NAND gate and a NOR gate using such methods.

Problem:

By extending the code in file proplog.hs

A - emulate nand, nor in terms of Not,Or and And.
    nand is true when at least one of its inputs is false

nor is true when both of its inputs are false

B - By using nand,nor,xor,impl,T,F build

a) 2 tautologies

b) a satisfiable formula

c) a unsatisfiable formula

Proplog.hs:

```
-- definition of basic gates 
data Prop = T | F |
  Not Prop |
  And Prop Prop |
Or Prop Prop 
deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

-- truth tables of basic gates

tt (Not F) = T
tt (Not T) = F
tt (And F F) = F
tt (And F T) = F
tt (And T F) = F
tt (And T T) = T

tt (Or F F) = F
tt (Or F T) = T
tt (Or T F) = T
tt (Or T T) = T

-- giving the tt of a derived gate
xor' F F = F
xor' F T = T
xor' T F = T
xor' T T = F

-- building the derived gate from Not, And, Or
xor x y = eval (And (Or x y) (Not (And x y)))

-- evaluating expressions made of logic gates

eval T = T
eval F = F
eval (Not x) = tt (Not (eval x))  
eval (And x y) = tt (And (eval x) (eval y))
eval (Or x y) = tt (Or (eval x) (eval y))

ite c t e = eval (Or (And c t) (And (Not c) e))

truthTable1 f = [(x,f x)|x<-[F,T]]

tt1 f = mapM_ print (truthTable1 f)

truthTable2 f = [((x,y),f x y)|x<-[F,T],y<-[F,T]]

tt2 f = mapM_ print (truthTable2 f)

truthTable3 f = [((x,y),f x y z)|x<-[F,T],y<-[F,T],z<-[F,T]]

tt3 f = mapM_ print (truthTable3 f)

or' x y = eval (Or x y)
and' x y = eval (And x y)
not' x = eval (Not x)

impl x y = eval (Or (Not x) y)

eq x y = eval (And (impl x y) (impl y x))

deMorgan1 x y = eq (Not (And x y)) (Or (Not x) (Not y))
deMorgan2 x y = eq (Not (Or x y)) (And (Not x) (Not y))


-- tautologies, satisfiable and unsatisfiable formulas

taut1 f = all (==T) [f x|x<-[F,T]]

taut2 f = all (==T) [f x y|x<-[F,T],y<-[F,T]]

sat1 f = any (==T) [f x|x<-[F,T]]

sat2 f = any (==T) [f x y|x<-[F,T],y<-[F,T]]

unsat1 f = not (sat1 f)
unsat2 f = not (sat2 f)

-- examples of tautologies: de Morgan1,2
-- examples of satisfiable formulas: xor, impl, ite

-- example of contradiction (unsatisfiable formulas): contr1
contr1 x = eval (And x (Not x))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write nand in terms of other gates but the better way is probably to define it directly:

```
-- Nand 
nand x y = not' (and' x y)

-- Nand - by definition
nand' F _ = T
nand' _ F = T
nand' _ _ = F
```

What is the greatest logical tautology? Modus ponens of course!

```
modusPonens p q = (p `and'` (p `impl` q)) `impl` q
prove_modusPonens = taut2 modusPonens
```

Here are some simple formulas:

```
f0 p q = p `and'` q 
satisfy_f0 = sat2 f0

f1 p = p `and'` (not' p)
satisfy_f1 = sat1 f1
```